# ASP.NET MVC 3 unit tests for Membership.CreateUser always return MembershipCreateStatus error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test for creating a new user and verifying that the desired redirect occurs. Here's my `Register` action, which is pretty much out-of-the-box code from a VS template:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

And the following is my test, using Moq. No matter what I set, I always get an error from one of the default `MembershipCreateStatus` error messages. For example:

> The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value

or

> The password retrieval answer provided is invalid

I've tried changing the `CreateUser` method to only call the username, password, and email overload, but it doesn't matter. It's like there's a check somewhere that is enforcing a password policy.

```
public void RegisterPost_WithAuthenticatedUser_RedirectsToHomeControllerIfSuccessful()
{
    // Arrange
    var accountController = new AccountController();
    var mockContext = GetMockRequestContext();

    ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockContext.Object, accountController);
    accountController.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

    RegisterModel registerModel = new RegisterModel() { UserName = "someone", Email = "someone@example.com", Password = "user", ConfirmPassword = "password" };

    // Act
    var result = accountController.Register(registerModel);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result.RouteData.Values["Controller"], Is.EqualTo("Home"));
    Assert.That(result.RouteData.Values["Action"], Is.EqualTo("Index"));
}
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: How does your `GetMockRequestContext()` look like?

Comment: @abatishchev My friend pointed out that I'm testing the already tested internal components within ASP.NET, so I'm changing my test approach. But it looks like this:
`Mock<RequestContext> GetMockContext(string roleName, bool isInRole, bool isAuthenticated){ var mockContext = new Mock<RequestContext>();
            var fakeUser = new Mock<IPrincipal>();

            fakeUser.Setup(p => p.IsInRole(roleName)).Returns(isInRole);
            fakeUser.Setup(p => p.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(isAuthenticated);

            mockContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext.User).Returns(fakeUser.Object);}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The static class/method issue strikes again!

the static method `Membership.CreateUser` is a hidden dependency here as it looks like your controller does not have a dependency, but actually it is dependent on this method, and you have not replaced (or been able to replace) this dependency in your test so you can control the interaction.

What you need to do, is to make this dependency explicit.  Do this by introducing an interface which model the interaction required with the membership provider (say called `IMembershipService`).

Create a default implementation of this which just delegates to the existing static methods like `Membership.CreateUser()`.  In your controller require an instance of this interface in the constructor (or create an instance of the default implementation in the default constructor if you must - not the preferred option, but...)

Then in your test create a mock of this interface and set the required expectations, and pass this mock to your controller, and verify it does what you would expect.

If you don't use a mock then you will keep creating new users in your db every time your test runs.  this might be ok, if you are resetting your db every time, but using a mock is simpler and quicker in the long run, although it takes a bit more effort to set up as you have to create a no null arg constructor controller and introduce a few interfaces to break up the implicit dependencies into explicit dependencies.

Comment: this would be my approach as well, and is actually what I do on the application that I work on. I think the default asp.net mvc 3 application already comes in with IMembershipService bundled in.

Answer (score 3):

The `Membership.CreateUser` is just a static wrapper, the task is actually delegated to the configured `MembershipProvider` implementation.

If you didn't configure a membership provider the default provider is used that is configured in the machine.config. For .NET v4.0 it looks like this on my machine:

```
<membership>
   <providers>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             applicationName="/" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             passwordFormat="Hashed" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
   </providers>
</membership>
```

Please note the attributes `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` and `minRequiredPasswordLength` that are enforcing certain rules by default.

I guess you do configure your own MembershipProvider in the web application, but most probably you forgot to take over this configuration for the unit test (into the app.config of the test project), and hence these default settings kick in.

Comment: +1 whilst this will probably work (and is a solution) i believe the better solution is to break this dependency on the static methods by introducing an interface

Comment: while this approach will work, it is not a good approach for unit testing. By adding AspNetSqlMembershipProvider suddenly your tests will be reliant on the SQL database, and this will severaly impact the performance and repeatability of your tests. Use an abstraction instead, as Sam pointed out.